# gsub to create new variables

Tags: r, gsub

I want to create 2 variables from 1 variable in `R`.

I have following character variable for gas station:

**station**

`Valero 1810 N Foster Rd & IH-10 E`

from this variable I want to create 2: `station_id` and `address`

**station_id**

Valero

**address**

`1810 N Foster Rd & IH-10 E`

In my data set all strings in `station` variable begin with words (up to 3 words, eg: EZ Mart) and all addresses begin with numeric value.

I was trying to achieve this goal using `gsub` for last couple hours but I couldn't do it.

Thank you

Comment: Check the above link from @MaxFt. The top suggestion using `tidyr::separate` will solve your problem nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution: This works for the sample string you give. You need to test if this works for your other cases. It would've been good to include more than one sample string.

```
ss <- "Valero 1810 N Foster Rd & IH-10 E";
station_id <- trimws(gsub("(\\w+\\s+){1,3}(\\d+.+)$", "\\1", ss));
address <- gsub("(\\w+\\s+){1,3}(\\d+.+)$", "\\2", ss);
station_id;
#[1] "Valero"
address;
#[1] "1810 N Foster Rd & IH-10 E"
```